# How can I write this R count query?

Tags: r

For the below data set I want the count of High, Above Normal, Normal under the given column

[image]

I want the output like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First creating a dummy dataset that looks similar to yours:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble::tribble(
          ~AL.01,         ~AL.02,         ~AL.03,
  "Above Normal", "Above Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",         "High",
        "Normal",       "Normal",         "High",
        "Normal",       "Normal", "Above Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
  "Above Normal",         "High", "Above Normal",
  "Above Normal",       "Normal", "Above Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "Normal",       "Normal",       "Normal",
        "High",       "Normal",       "Normal"
  )
```

Now perform the following count and rename operations:

```
AL.01 <- dat %>% 
  count(AL.01) %>% 
  rename(metric = AL.01, AL.01 = n)
AL.02 <- dat %>% 
  count(AL.02) %>% 
  rename(metric = AL.02, AL.02 = n)
AL.03 <- dat %>% 
  count(AL.03) %>% 
  rename(metric = AL.03, AL.03 = n)

final <- full_join(AL.01, AL.02) %>% full_join(AL.03)


final
```

The data.frame `final` should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  metric       AL.01 AL.02 AL.03
  <chr>        <int> <int> <int>
1 Above Normal     3     1     3
2 High             1     1     2
3 Normal          19    21    18
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R, you could execute the following code:

```
#mock up data
my_df <- data.frame(AL_01 = c("Above No", "Normal", "Normal", "High", "Above No", "Normal", "Normal", "High"),
                    AL_02 = c("Above No", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Above No", "Normal", "Normal", "High"),
                    AL_03 =  c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "High","Above No", "Normal", "Normal", "High" ))

apply(my_df, 2, table)
```

yielding:

```
         AL_01 AL_02 AL_03
Above No     2     2     1
High         2     1     2
Normal       4     5     5
```

The `table` command counts the number of different entries in a vector. This is called  within an `apply` function. This way, the `table` command is executed for every column (because of the second argument == 2) and returned.
Type `?table` and `?apply` at the command prompt to get more information.

Comment: This is a much more simple and elegant answer than what I posted. Thanks.

Comment: @RachitKinger Your solution helps the OP as well, and that is what counts (the most).